# How to print or return the elements in a set with newlines that separate them in alphabetical order?

Tags: python

For example,

if there is a set with elements `[Alex, Bill, Brian, Chris]`

How can I print it in the following format?

```
Alex

Bill, Brian

Chris
```

I've tried using a nested for loop that checks the first letter of every element, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient method.

Comment: Show your code that you wrote that does not solve the problem.

Comment: By "set", do you mean "set" or "list"? I ask because `[Alex, Bill, Brian, Chris]` is a list literal. Set literals have curly brackets. It's an important distinction, because only one of those types has a sort method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
l = ['Alex', 'Bill', 'Brian', 'Chris']
groups = itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x[0])
for item in gb:
    print(', '.join(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of code which doesn't need any nested loop (just a for loop)

```
myList=['Alex','Bill','Brian','Chris'] # Data type can be set too
myList=sorted(myList) # sorted() will return a sorted list of your given list or set
for i in range(len(myList)-1):
    f=myList[i]
    s=myList[i+1]
    if f[0]!=s[0]:
        print(f)
    else:
        print(f,end=', ')
print(myList[-1])
```